# How to get Play Store internal testing updates appear online faster

Tags: android, google-play, google-developers-console

We are just starting with our first app and trying to update an internal testing version, but it takes forever to appear in the store. The first (internal testing) version took 2 days which is maybe understandable, but now we need to do some debugging and we can't keep waiting hours or days for every small update to be available for testing.

It would be easier to just create APKs and install on the phone locally, but those are working perfectly while the bundle uploaded to the Play Store has an issue that the APK doesn't have... so our only option is to do the debugging through the play store.

Is this normal and is there any way of getting internal testing updates available right away?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: @CommonsWare  I disagree!

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't see anything in that page that answers the OP's question.

Comment: @dlchambers: That is because questions regarding the policies of app distribution channels is deemed to be off-topic for Stack Overflow. The linked-to Meta post discusses this.

Comment: @CommonsWare got it, thanks for the quick clarification

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I have the same issues (crashing app only with play store and also very slow publishing of internal-only aab).

But - how strange! - just after posting this, my app came through! Spooky...

Comment: They always take a while, so just be patient... all I can say ;)